# How to make Dropbox camera upload appear immediately on PC?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I use my android phone with dropbox and the camera upload function. But after it uploads images to cloud. The PC client doesn't do anything to download the image even after "pause syncing" and "resume syncing"  again.  I have to restart dropbox PC client to get the newly uploaded images in my PC dropbox folder. 
How to make Dropbox camera upload appear immediately on PC? Or it is a dropbox bug for now?

Comment: Sounds a bit helpless, but have you tried uninstalling Dropbox and reinstalling the latest version?

Comment: I 've always had this problem since 1.* to now. I don' t know if photos will appear in a very short time at your place?

Comment: Just recently I uploaded about 90 pictures from my phone to Dropbox and almost immediately after the Android client had finished uploading a single picture a message popped up on my PC saying that there was a new file. So, yes, the indented behaviour is that it syncs almost instantaneously.

Comment: I ' m using the Linux version of dropbox, I don' t know if it's related, though.

Comment: Me too, on Ubuntu 12.04 and Arch Linux. Both machines don't have any notable lag in syncing. Sorry not to be of more help.